# vertical text alignment in minipages

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, text

I typed the following code into my Tex file:

```
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{27pt}6)\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{6.25in}\includegraphics{image}
\end{minipage}
```

Actual Behavior: below left. Desired Behavior: below right.  I thought the [t] would fix it but it didn't.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Note that [t] and [b] are in relation to the first or last baseline in the minipage. But the image is just one very tall line. I'd have a look at the features of the `adjustbox` package. BTW: (1) Please always provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. (2) Use only images that others have access to use or use say `\rule{5cm}{5cm}`. Users are expected to always have access to the images that come with the `mwe` package, thus use can always use the images listed here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe

Comment: add `\null` at the bottom of the minipage. Also enclose everything in `fbox`, if you want to visualize what is happening.

Comment: ^Just tried \null but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @daleif said in the comments, you can do this easily with the `adjustbox` package. Also, it looks like you're trying to add the image into a numbered list. Why not just use the `enumerate` environment?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=t]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: example image top-aligned with enumerate item]

Comment: Thanks :-)  What part of the code is the adjustbox package needed for?

Comment: The `adjustbox` package is needed for the `valign=t` option in the `\includegraphics`. This option forces the image to be aligned at its top and not at its baseline (which is actually at its bottom)

Comment: I took away the minipages and just put the text and the image next to it with the valign=t and it worked!  Thanks again.